# Django routing not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I know there should be a little thing that i missed. But I couldn't figure the problem out for ours. And I give up. Here is my root url conf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('admin.urls')),
]
```

And admin.urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^user$', views.user, name='user'),

]
```

When i hit "localhost/" index works great. But localhost/user (localhost/user/ too) is not working, i get 404 not found. admin is my application name so do not confuse it with django.contrib.admin.

Django version :(1, 11, 5, 'final', 0)

Python 3.6.2

Comment: When you `include`, it includes them *under* the url specified... so in this case you don't want the `^$` which means "no path specified" as adding to the end of that doesn't make sense... it's possible that `''` is what you want there, then `/user` will work

Comment: Yes, it works now, Thanks.